@tanstack/react-router - aria-current="page" on parent <Link> still set on child routes?
I'm using @tanstack/react-router file-based routing. I have links in my __root.tsx element. Let's say some of these links point to /route1, /route2, /route3.
In my global scss file, I have a line like this, which disables links with property aria-current="page"
[aria-current="page"] {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Whenever I'm on a page of that route, such as /route1, the link is disabled, which is expected behavior. But, when I'm on a child route (route1/$id), the link is still disabled. This makes no sense to me, because I cannot navigate up the /route1 from the child route.
In Chrome's inspect, the <Link> element looks like this:
<a class="false active" href="/route1" data-status="active" aria-current="page">Route1</a>

and still includes those two properties, even though it's not on the /route1 route anymore, it's on a child route. Is this expected behavior? I assumed that aria-current="page" prop would be undefined when it's on the child route, but it's not.
Uncommenting the scss block above fixed it, but I would still like to have any a elements with aria-current="page" property have that behavior.
Is there any way to fix this and also keep the scss block?
As mentioned above, I was expecting aria-current="page" to be removed from the /route1 link once I routed to a child page, but it's only undefined on neighbor routes, not child routes.
